# How to use __func__ in macros

Tags: c, function, macros

I am trying to create a macro that will modify a field in a data structure based on the function name in which the macro is invoked, see below:

```
#define REGISTER(func_name) data.func_name##_n++

struct data
{
    int func_name_n;
} data;

void func_name(void)
{
    REGISTER(func_name);
}

int main(void)
{
    func_name();
    return 0; 
}
```

I want to use the `__func__` macro, so the user could just type `REGISTER` and the function name will be passed automatically:

```
#define REGISTER(func_name) data.func_name##_n++
#define REGISTER_WRAP REGISTER(__func__)

REGISTER_WRAP;
```

but I get the following error:

```
error: ‘struct data’ has no member named ‘__func___n’
```

**Is there a way to use `__func__` in the macro and obtain the desired result?**

Comment: No, there is no easy way to achieve your wishes.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, what is the hard way?

Comment: Maybe customizing GCC using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)

Comment: There might be a cleaner solution to your real problem. What's the real problem?

Comment: I want to count how many times functions are called, for simplicity I wanted to use something like COUNT_THIS_FUNCTION, and the name be resolved automatically

Comment: @RSahu : Agreed - looks like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` is a macro, `__func__` is a variable.

Comment: This would be such a piece of cake if C++ was an option.

Comment: @Clifford No, according to the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html), `__FUNCTION__` is at best a macro which perversely expands to `__func__`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter : That's the documentation to GCC not necessarily true of all compilers. Last time I used GCC extensively it was pre v3.4 where __FUNCTION__ was a string literal not a variable - still not strictly a pre-processor macro, although many sources refer to them as *"predefined macros"*.

Comment: @Clifford Well, `__FUNCTION__` is an extension and won't even exist on some platforms. In general, if the preprocessor is literally a step carried out before semantic analysis, it cannot know the name of the current function. Implementation as a macro depends on simultaneous preprocessing and analysis. Not a good thing for a program to depend on.

Answer (score 2):

`__func__` is not a macro. It's an implicitly created variable:

```
static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
```

You can't use its value at compile time.